# How do you write to the OSX System keychain?

Tags: macos, cocoa, keychain

As part of the process of creating a VPN connection programatically in OSX, using Cocoa, I need to store the PPP password in the System keychain.  When I try to do this using the keychain API, I get the following error as a result of calling SecKeychainAddGenericPassword:

"Could not write to the file. It may have been opened with insufficient access privileges."

Here is the code I am using:

```
- (void)storePasswordInKeychain
{
    SecKeychainRef keychain = nil;
    err = SecKeychainCopyDomainDefault(kSecPreferencesDomainSystem, &keychain);
    if (err != errSecSuccess) {
        NSLog(@"Error getting system keychain: %@", SecCopyErrorMessageString(err, NULL));
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Succeeded opening keychain: %@", SecCopyErrorMessageString(err, NULL));
        SecKeychainItemRef item = nil;        
        err = SecKeychainUnlock(keychain, 0, NULL, FALSE);
        NSLog(@"Keychain unlocked: %@", SecCopyErrorMessageString(err, NULL));

        err = SecKeychainAddGenericPassword (keychain, 
                                         3, "VPN", 
                                         8, "username",
                                         8, "password",
                                         &item);
        NSLog(@"Result of storing password: %@", SecCopyErrorMessageString(err, NULL));
    }
}
```

The discussion [How to write to the System.keychain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312498/how-to-write-to-the-system-keychain/9837040#9837040) makes it seem like I need to make a command line call to /usr/bin/security from within my program, but the point of the Keychain API seems to be to avoid that kind of hackery.

Can anybody point me in the right direction for storing a new password in the System keychain?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need root privilege when you write something to system keychain.
For xcode debugging, you just "EditScheme"(From Menu by "Product->EditScheme...->Run->Info->Debug process as->root"). Well,my xcode version is 6.1, maybe there is some difference in different xcode version.
Or just use command line by sudo your app.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer Helpful but the issue is when i run "application.App" password not store in SYSTEM KEYCHAIN. Please guid me i will be very thankful?

Answer (score 1):

It is true that the credentials need to go into the system keychain and not the user keychain. You will not need the SMJobBless to do that.

After you unlocked the keychain, create an SecAccessRef like so:

```
SecAccessRef access = nil;
status = SecAccessCreate(CFSTR("Some VPN Test"), (__bridge CFArrayRef)(self.trustedApps), &access);
```

Then build your keychain item

```
SecKeychainAttribute attrs[] = {
  {kSecLabelItemAttr, (int)strlen(labelUTF8), (char *)labelUTF8},
  {kSecAccountItemAttr, (int)strlen(accountUTF8), (char *)accountUTF8},
  {kSecServiceItemAttr, (int)strlen(serviceUTF8), (char *)serviceUTF8},
  {kSecDescriptionItemAttr, (int)strlen(descriptionUTF8), (char *)descriptionUTF8},
};
```

And finally store it to the keychain:

```
  SecKeychainAttributeList attributes = {sizeof(attrs) / sizeof(attrs[0]), attrs};
  status = SecKeychainItemCreateFromContent(kSecGenericPasswordItemClass, &attributes, (int)strlen(passwordUTF8), passwordUTF8, keychain, access, &item);
```

There is a project on Github which does just that. Have a look at the `VPNKeychain.m` file to see the whole implementation. https://github.com/halo/macosvpn

Comment: Sir i am user the macosvpn Project but code run successfully and create new network but it's not showing data which i passes e.g  Server address, Account Name

Comment: i have install helperTool successfully in Mac application and use https://github.com/halo/macosvpn code, still  source code not store password in System Keychain when i set Debug Process as (Me). Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Surely a VPN username & password belong to a particular user, do you really mean the system keychain and not the user keychain?

Try dropping the calls to `SecKeychainCopyDomainDefault` & `SecKeychainUnlock` and just pass `NULL` as the first argument to `SecKeychainAddGenericPassword` - this should add the item to the default keychain.

Comment: Unfortunately, the VPN password does belong to the system, not the user, keychain.  If you manually create a new PPTP VPN connection through system preferences and open keychain, you can see that the VPN password gets stored in the system keychain.

Comment: I've no idea offhand and I'm on the wrong machine to test, but does it *need* to be in the system keychain? I.e. if you add it to the user keychain is it ignored? If so maybe you'll have to have the user always enter it.

Comment: To test this, I manually created a new vpn connection in network preferences.  I connected to it just fine.  Then I opened Keychain Access and moved the keychain item that stores the password from the system keychain to the login keychain.  When I tried to reconnect, it prompted me for my vpn password.  So it really does need to go in the system keychain.

Comment: i have install helperTool successfully in Mac application and use https://github.com/halo/macosvpn code, still  source code not store password in System Keychain when i set Debug Process as (Me). Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Apple's current recommendation for privileged access is to use the [Service Management](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Reference/ServiceManagementFwRef/ServiceManagement_h/) API. They have a sample project: [SMJobBless](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SMJobBless/Introduction/Intro.html). I'm not sure if the sandbox will allow system keychain access if you are targeting the Mac App Store.

The other question you point to seems to be recommending the [Authorization Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Reference/SecurityFoundationFramework/Classes/SFAuthorization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) API which Service Management replaced (in 10.6) and which is explicitly stated as not being allowed at all when sandboxed.

Comment: i have install helperTool successfully in Mac application and use https://github.com/halo/macosvpn code, still  source code not store password in System Keychain when i set Debug Process as (Me). Can anyone help me?